# How can I install recessed lights with a thick ceiling finish?

Tags: lighting

I have an old house with a lath and plaster ceiling that has 1x4 battens installed on the lath and plaster ceiling with 3/8" drywall over those.

I want to install recessed lighting but there is approximately 1" gap between the can and the trim. Are there recessed light cans available that are adjustable to accommodate that?

Comment: To summarize, you want to know if there are any remodel style recessed light cans that work with a ceiling thickness of around 1" rather than the typical 1/2" drywall?

Comment: Sounds like the thickness is more like 2":  7/8" (plaster) + 3/4" (battens) + 3/8" (drywall).

Comment: Welcome, Jim. Sorry I tore up your first question. It needed some clarity and other fixes. Good luck.